# How to stop a log stream that has been started in cloud watch by cloud watch agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

How to stop a log stream that has been started in ec2 by  cloud watch agent. How to delete or permanently stop sending logs from that log_group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `sudo service awslogs stop`
>
> Will stop all the logs that are going
>
> If you want to stop a particular log-group and continue sending others Use this:
>
> `sudo service awslogs stop (log-group name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the log-group, select log-group -> action -> delete

But why you are not stopping the agent itself?

> At a command prompt, type the following command:
>
> `sudo service awslogs stop`
>
> If you are running Amazon Linux 2, type the  following command:
>
> `sudo service awslogsd stop`

[StopTheCWLAgent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/StopTheCWLAgent.html)

Or if you want to delete all log-group then

```
aws logs describe-log-groups --query 'logGroups[*].logGroupName' --output table | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ^$ | while read x; do aws logs delete-log-group --log-group-name $x; done
```

[clear all log-group](https://gist.github.com/pahud/1e875cb1252a622173cc2236be5c2963)

Comment: thanks i figured out another way to stop if i need to stop only particular log-group